# 404 Error for a Jersey Tomcat web server created in eclipse with java

Tags: java, rest, web, server, eclipse-wtp

I created a server starting from a dynamic web project. When I make a request to it by typing

```
http://localhost:8080/restserver/myserver
```

or

```
http://localhost:8080/restserver/myserver/myserver
```

into the search bar of my web browser I receive the response

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message /restserver/src/demo/demo

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
```

I don't know what I need to change with my server program. I've been following [this tutorial](https://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/) to set my server up, and it doesn't look like they have much more than me.

My expected response to my request is

[image]

I've tried just about everything. Deleting and reinstalling eclipse and tomcat, removing my ~/.m2/repository folder. The log file looks basically [like this](https://coderanch.com/t/689802/application-servers/stop-memory-leak-Tomcat-Eclipse),

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2018:13:09:20 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1074
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Dec/2018:13:11:13 -0600] "GET /RestServer HTTP/1.1" 302 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Dec/2018:13:11:13 -0600] "GET /RestServer/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1089
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Dec/2018:13:11:14 -0600] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1085
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Dec/2018:13:11:19 -0600] "GET /RestServer/myserver HTTP/1.1" 404 1097
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Dec/2018:13:11:19 -0600] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1085
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Dec/2018:13:11:24 -0600] "GET /RestServer/myserver/myserver HTTP/1.1" 404 1110
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Dec/2018:13:11:24 -0600] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1085
```

(I have know idea where the 302 cam from, just saw this)

so I'm thinking it might be that the requests aren't being authenticated because of the - in the third column? I also don't understand the [catalina.properties file](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5374-install-tomcat6), but I followed those instructions and it didn't help. I also read a few things about proxies that I didn't really understand because I couldn't figure out how to disable proxies.

---

## RestServer/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>RestServer</groupId>
  <artifactId>RestServer</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20170516</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

**RestServer/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RestServer</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/serv/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

## RestServer/Java Resources/src/serverPackage/MyServer.java

```
package serverPackage;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/myserver")
public class MyServer {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String convertCtoF() {

        Double fahrenheit;
        Double celsius = 36.8;
        fahrenheit = ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;

        String result = "@Produces(\"application/xml\") Output: \n\nC to F Converter Output: \n\n" + fahrenheit;
        return "<ctofservice>" + "<celsius>" + celsius + "</celsius>" + "<ctofoutput>" + result + "</ctofoutput>" + "</ctofservice>";
    }

    @Path("{c}")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String convertCtoFfromInput(@PathParam("c") Double c) {
        Double fahrenheit;
        Double celsius = c;
        fahrenheit = ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;

        String result = "@Produces(\"application/xml\") Output: \n\nC to F Converter Output: \n\n" + fahrenheit;
        return "<ctofservice>" + "<celsius>" + celsius + "</celsius>" + "<ctofoutput>" + result + "</ctofoutput>" + "</ctofservice>";
    }
}
```

---

## My current file directory

[image]

[image]

---

**Update**

I changed

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/serv/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

to

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/serv/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And now when I visit http://localhost:8080/RestServer/serv/myserver

```
I receive the error

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Root Cause

java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext not present
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1138)
    com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getClass(ReflectionHelper.java:629)
    com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getClass(ReflectionHelper.java:625)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ContextResolverFactory.getParameterizedType(ContextResolverFactory.java:202)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ContextResolverFactory.init(ContextResolverFactory.java:89)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1332)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1328)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1138)
    com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getClass(ReflectionHelper.java:629)
    com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getClass(ReflectionHelper.java:625)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ContextResolverFactory.getParameterizedType(ContextResolverFactory.java:202)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ContextResolverFactory.init(ContextResolverFactory.java:89)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1332)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Updated local_host_accesslog

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2018:01:34:47 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1074
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Dec/2018:01:39:55 -0600] "GET /myserver HTTP/1.1" 404 1082
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Dec/2018:01:39:57 -0600] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1085
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Dec/2018:01:40:15 -0600] "GET /RestServer/myserver HTTP/1.1" 404 1097
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Dec/2018:01:40:21 -0600] "GET /RestServer/serv/myserver HTTP/1.1" 500 10064
```

---

**Updated pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>RestServer</groupId>
  <artifactId>RestServer</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20170516</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: try with http://localhost:8080/RestServer/restserver/ctofservice/10

Comment: @Elgayed I get the same error

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/restserver/src/demo/demo` the webserver will not mirror your source file system. You have to tell the webserver exactly which resources are to be mapped.

Comment: @patrickf Thats one of the ones I posted, but no combination works, I don't think its the url, I think it's something else, I researched the url a bunch and tried lots of different combinations

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:8080/serv/myserver`?

Comment: I could not recollect if space (**Faces Servlet**) is correct to have or not  in `servlet-name` tag.

Comment: @secretsuperstar I made some changes to the web.xml file and receive a 500 error code response now, so I think that means I'm connecting now

Comment: as per new error, the class `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` is not found. you may need to update the maven dependency

Comment: I think you need to pass `<init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>com.resources</param-value>
  </init-param>` in `web.xml` under `servlet-class`. here `com.resources` refers to your resource class

Comment: Try adding `<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: @secretsuperstar Yeah that did it, thank-you. I think I used to have my servlet as whats listed there until I used `version 3` of `dynamic web module` instead of `version 4`, all my version 4 attempts at this project though would return the 404 error, Do you know anything about that?

Comment: currently which version of dynamic web module is the app running and which version does not work?

Comment: I'm running version 3, version 4 wasn't working but that could have possibly been due to other things, but I don't know I unstalled eclipse and tomcat and cleared all the repositories I was reading out and no solutions helped with version 4, perhaps I was missing something though.

Comment: I am able to run with `version 4` too.. I ran the project -> run on server -> selected **tomcat 9** and then run. I have used **java 8**.

Comment: and I have changed dynamic web-module to version 4

Comment: @Jacob, Please update with answer as you have almost found solution on your own. Thanks

Comment: @secretsuperstar No no, post the stuff about the faces servlet and the dependency and I'll mark that as correct because that's what got me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Jersey controller `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer` in your mapping and specify the resources path

```
<init-param> 
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> 
   <param-value>com.resources</param-value>  <!--comma separated packages-->
</init-param>
```

and add dependency for class `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext`

```
<dependency> 
   <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId> 
   <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId> 
   <version>2.2.6</version> 
</dependency>
```

With respect to web module version 4, I am able to run the application. I am using java 8 and tomcat 9.

[image]

Please post comments if you require help for the same

Comment: Thank-you. This worked, but I tried adding some other java files that would run on my server and got the 404 error again, I added a dependency (`<groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.1</version>`) and after a few clean's, maven updates, ... I started getting the errors `File not found: /Users/Sam/eclipse-workspacenewest/RestServer/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/maven/RestServer/RestServer/pom.xml.
File not found: /Users/Sam/eclipse-workspacenewest/RestServer/target/classes/serverPackage/.DS_Store.`

Comment: Is it failing to locate pom.xml

Comment: Sorry, I thought that my comment included something like this `File not found: ~/eclipse-workspacenewest/RestServer/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/Manifest.MF (no such file or directory)` it looks like that file is missing

Comment: Did you change pom.xml .. when are getting the error.. try adding META-INF folder and Manifest.MF file inside it.. you can add the META-INF under resources source folder.. if one not present create one source folder with that name

Comment: Update pom.xml or any other changes if you have made

Comment: I posted another copy of my pom.xml, I don't know what I might have messed up in it

Comment: It's working again, I don't know what I keep changing but it seems to work randomly

Comment: just had a look at pom.xml, which version of java you would like to use. in pom.xml, you are using 1.6, however that should not cause any issue as long as the dependencies are compiled with 1.6 or lower version though

Comment: so, how is the xml and pom files supposed to be? I can't understand

Answer (score 2):

Although the build wass SUCCESS I gοt initially a HTTP Status 404 – Not Found. I followed all previous suggestions and I got in console a similar error. After following the markers errors and warning and searched a little bit.

First step:

I went to project right click -> properties -> Deployment Assembly and I added the Maven Depencencies Libray, after that another severe warning appeared.

Second Step: It seemed that a depedency in `pom` was needed to work flawlessly

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

just before jaxb-api

The major problem for me for all those frameworks working together are the settings in eclipse. you need to be able to have installed and connected compatible resources. For example, I also managed to run properly the Dynamic Web Project 4.0 like mentioned above

Third Step:

It came to my attention that you mention this

```
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.8.0</version>
<configuration>
  <source>1.6</source>
  <target>1.6</target>
</configuration>
```

In that case, mentioning `source` and `target` version means that your whole project is going to be compiled in Java 1.6 compatibility. Maybe that is why you couldn't run it as a Dynamic Web Project 4.0 because it needs Java 1.8 and newer.
In my scenario, I set up all the preferences right, then executed that pom and it reverted everything to Java 1.6 in the options, so I just removed it and it executed properly